# Install gem from ruby script and use it afterwards

Tags: ruby, bash, rubygems, geminabox

I have a private gemserver running by Geminabox. To publish any gem there, there is a command `gem inabox my-gem.gem -g $HOST`.

I'm working on a script for automated publishing new gem versions.

So I have something like:

```
`gem install geminabox --no-ri --no-rdoc`
`gem inabox my-super-gem.gem`
```

The problem is it returns the following:

```
Successfully installed reentrant_flock-0.1.0
Successfully installed multipart-post-2.0.0
Successfully installed faraday-0.13.1
Successfully installed nesty-1.0.2
Successfully installed httpclient-2.8.3
Successfully installed builder-3.2.3
Successfully installed mustermann-1.0.1
Successfully installed rack-2.0.3
Successfully installed rack-protection-2.0.0
Successfully installed tilt-2.0.8
Successfully installed sinatra-2.0.0
Successfully installed geminabox-0.13.9
12 gems installed
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command inabox
```

When I do the same manually in a console, everything works fine. The same if I put these commands into `.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
gem install geminabox --no-ri --no-rdoc
gem inabox -g $RUBYGEMS_HOST my-awesome.gem
```

But, again, if I call this script from ruby, it does not work with the same error (`Unknown command inabox`):

```
system('script/upload_gem.sh')
```

I need to use the script exactly from Ruby. Any ideas why it does not work?

Comment: You normally just publish gems by running `rake release`. No need to write a custom script for it.

Comment: @TomLord As I can judge from code of `rake-release` gem, it uses `gem push` command undercover, which doesn't work in my case

Comment: Why? All you should need to do is define the gem server in your `gemfile`.

Comment: @TomLord remote private gemserver is running with geminabox and it is some sort of incorrectly configured. It denies access for standard gemcutter API request to upload a new gem. With `gem inabox` command, otherwise, it works fine.

I have no access to rubygems server, so there is no option to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, I solved the problem digging into `gemianbox` gem - it seems it uploads gem with a simple POST request, so `gem inabox` command isn't necessary at all, uploading can be achieved with a simple CURL command:

`curl -F 'file=@/some/file.gem' https://some.host/upload`